# Dynamic Batch Updates from Another Collection Firebase Firestore

Tags: swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have two collections where one will be updating itself every month or so. I want to update the other collection is user-created and the this list contains SOME of the documents the first collection contains.

Q1C and Q1P (credit card rewards category and percentage) would change every quarter. When another quarter begins, I'll submit the new values, but userlist collection won't know what fields to read since I didn't update that one(since that one is user-created). The only way to update the new userlist information seems to be that you have to delete the document and then write it again from the Cards collection, which doesn't seem like the best approach. Will transactions work in this situation?

The one that updates every month is called Cards: [image]

The other collection is userlist. This collection only has some of the documents that Cards have. [image]
So my main question is that how should I update the document fields in the userlist collection when the Cards collection is updated?
e.g. Capital One Venture document in Cards collection got updated where "Q1P" now becomes 3 instead of 5, and I also want to sync the new information in userlist so that "Q1P" also becomes 3.

I noticed that since the number of cards in the Cards collection is different than the userlist collection, so we have to update the document fields dynamically(I think).
As of right now, I'm just updating all the data by hand(hard-coded) :

```
                db.collection("userlist").document("Capital One Venture").updateData(["Q1P": 3]) { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription) 
                }
                print("sucessfully updated data")
            }
```

It's in Swift, but I can take other programming langs. Thanks :)

Also, I can't just update all my documents from the Cards collection to userlist or else it just becomes another Cards collection :(

Comment: It looks like you already have a solution to your problem.  Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: I want to update all the documents fields in userlist as well from Cards collection as well. Think of like an auto-update system for the whole list of documents. And I don't want to make everything hard-coded cuz in the end it won't work out.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I don't want to make everything hard-coded cuz in the end it won't work out".  You can simply write code to update both collections.  What won't work about that?  What is the real problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: When Cards collection updates, userlist will also update but it should not include the other documents that Cards collection has... Wait, one question, Merging it will work right?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking.  I suggest going back to your question and edit it to better explain the problem and where you are stuck.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, everything needs to be in the question itself.